# Custom Knockout binding not working correctly

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I created a computed observable that works well formatting phone numbers. It will take a string of numbers and strip it down to this format xxx-xxx-xxxx when focus is off the form field. then I a have a controller action stripping it down to format xxxxxxxxxx before it persists to the database. Then my computed observable re-formats it to the xxx-xxx-xxxx format.

I now want the to create a reusable custom binding handler that can be implemented across our application. The problem is that I cannot get it to do the last part where it re-formats it back in the form field. So, the issue is when I click update, the form field displays the number as xxxxxxxxxx (the same way as it is in the DB) Does anyone know what I need to change to make by custom binding work like my current computed observable?

**Observable:**

```
self.Phone = ko.observable(model.MainPhone ? model.MainPhone : "").extend({ maxLength: 20, minLength: 10 });
```

**Computed Observable working correctly:**

```
self.PhoneFormat = ko.computed(function () {
   var phoneFormatting = self.Phone()
       .replace(/\D+/g, "")
       .replace(/^[01]/, "")
       .replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3")
       .substring(0, 12);
   return self.Phone() ? self.Phone(phoneFormatting) : "";
}, self);
```

**Custom binding not working correctly:**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.formatPhone = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        var source = valueAccessor();
        var formatter = function () {
            return ko.computed({
                read: function() { return source(); },
                write: function(newValue) {
                    source(newValue.replace(/\D+/g, "")
                        .replace(/^[01]/, "")
                        .replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3")
                        .substring(0, 12));
                }
            });
        };

        ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, formatter, allBindings);
    },

    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        var source = valueAccessor();
        var formatter = function() {
            return ko.computed({
                read: function() { return source(); },
                write: function(newValue) {
                    source(newValue.replace(/\D+/g, "")
                        .replace(/^[01]/, "")
                        .replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3")
                        .substring(0, 12));
                }
            });
        };

        ko.bindingHandlers.value.update(element, formatter, allBindings);
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you show the code related to "when I click update"? Is that a button? What does the update do exactly?

Comment: Sure Jason! It is a button and the controller code is below:


`client.ContactPhone = phoneNumber == null ? null : Regex.Replace(phoneNumber, @"[^\d]", "");`

Comment: Oh and it used to update any changes to fields on the customer info page.

Comment: Take out your `update` function and replace the `value.init` call with `ko.applyBindingAccessorsToNode(element, { value: formatter }, bindingContext)` (You also need to expand your `init` to get `bindingContext`).

Answer (score 1):

It feels like the `read` and `write` should be swapped around...

I'd say you want your "source" data to be just the numbers. The formatted data is mainly for display purposes.

I'd expect a `computed` layer added in your binding, that does two things:

- When writing, remove the formating before putting it in the `source`
- When reading, add in the correct format

I'm not sure if I broke stuff that you had working previously, but it could be something like:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.formatPhone = {
  init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        var source = valueAccessor();
        var formatter = ko.computed({
          write: function(newValue) {
             source(newValue.split("-").join("")); 
          },
          read: function() {
            return source().replace(/\D+/g, "")
                   .replace(/^[01]/, "")
                   .replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3")
                   .substring(0, 12);
          }
        });

        ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, function() { return formatter; }, allBindings);
    }
};

var vm = { phoneNr: ko.observable("3456546512") };

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
Via custom binding:
<input data-bind="formatPhone: phoneNr">
<br/>
Mimic external update:
<input data-bind="textInput: phoneNr">
```

Comment: Thanks Jason. It works like a charm! Have you been using Knockout for a long time?

Comment: Actually I got stuck in a meeting and user3297291 beat me to it. Maybe his name is Jason too though ;)

Comment: Ha! Just realized it wasn't you... :) 

Thanks user!

Comment: @user3297291 There still seems to be a problem. the formatiing works when I initially move focus away from the field. However, if I go back to it a second time, add some leading space, and some special characters it does not re-evaluate the value and reformat it. :( Any ideas?

Comment: @JasonSpake There still seems to be a problem. the formatting works when I initially move focus away from the field. However, if I go back to it a second time, add some leading space, and some special characters it does not re-evaluate the value and reformat it. :( Any ideas?

Comment: I ended up going with a subscribable and it works perfectly. I will post the code as the chosen answer.

Comment: The write function here is looking for a particular pattern so if the user inputs random characters that don't match it isn't going to work right. You might be better off matching on the numeric characters instead of looking for a specific pattern. Try newValue.match(/\d+/g).join("");

Comment: Also if you want to give the reusable binding another go definitely incorporate Michael Best's comments above. He's one of the primary contributors to the knockout library!

Comment: I tried to focus my answer on the relationship between a the source data and the display data. The `write` string formatting was meant more as an example on "this is where you clean your user input" and left for you to fine-tune. I think you should try to come up with two methods, e.g. `formatAsPhoneNr` and `cleanPhoneNr`, and write some tests for them. The crux of my answer still is: only write data to the source in the format that you want in your back-end/model. The computed takes care of the UI/UX layer.

Comment: My apologies user3297291, my suggestions were meant to be directed at @DeanFriedland and were not intended to nitpick your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this works but the custom binding did not. :(

**HTML:**

```
<input data-bind="value: Phone" />
```

**KO Observable:**

```
self.Phone = ko.observable(model.Phone ? model.Phone : "").trimmed();
```

**KO Subscribable:**

```
ko.subscribable.fn.trimmed = function () {
        return ko.computed({
            read: function () {
                return this().replace(/\D+/g, "")
                               .replace(/^[01]/, "")
                               .replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3")
                               .substring(0, 12);
            },
            write: function (value) {
                this(value.replace(/\D+/g, "")
                               .replace(/^[01]/, "")
                               .replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3")
                               .substring(0, 12));
                this.valueHasMutated();
            },
            owner: this
        }).extend({ notify: 'always' });
    };
```